# Apache POI word XWPF - How to find a link between a comment and paragraph?

Tags: apache-poi, xwpf

I need to find a text associated with a paragraph comment but cannot find what links those two. The comment list consists of IDs which seams to be a commentID, however when iterating over paragraphs I cannot see a method that would return linked comments.
Does somebody know how to get paragraph text associated with a comment?

Comment: When iterating over document body elements and then parts relationships I can see  comments part but have no idea how to proceed from there.

Comment: <script src="https://gist.github.com/wbialy/36f3e8fef0c83755a13f40dbd0fd8681.js"></script>

Comment: Please edit your question so it shows what you have tried. Show your code there instead of putting an unsuccessfull linkt to [github](https://gist.github.com/wbialy/36f3e8fef0c83755a13f40dbd0fd8681) in a comment. Btw.: [XWPFWordExtractor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/extractor/XWPFWordExtractor.html) is able getting comments. It uses a [XWPFCommentsDecorator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/model/XWPFCommentsDecorator.html) created using `XWPFCommentsDecorator decorator = new XWPFCommentsDecorator(paragraph, null);`.